# Make Windows XP taskbar icons draggable

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

In Windows 7, taskbar icons are draggable so we can reorder icons. I was wondering if that's possible in Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean moving the program buttons, like you can on Windows 7?

Use [Taskbar Shuffle](http://lifehacker.com/207132/download-of-the-day-taskbar-shuffle-20-windows).

Comment: Since the program's website has exceeded its bandwidth quota, here's a [CNET link](http://download.cnet.com/Taskbar-Shuffle/3000-2072_4-10531265.html).

Comment: This tool is awesome. Don't know shuffle program buttons is that easy! Thanks torbengb and Dennis.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the Quick Launch icons? Right-click the taskbar and uncheck 'Lock the taskbar'. Now you can rearrange them.